# Error with multiple font-face declarations

Tags: css, html, font-face

CSS `@font-face` rules:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: light;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And their uses:

```
.ingrijirea-main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-color: #2A2D4C;
    color: white;
    height: 500px;
}

.ingrijirea-title {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .ingrijirea-title-bottom {
        font-weight: lighter;
        font-style: italic;
    }
}

.ingrijirea-text {
    font-size: 1.28em;
    font-weight: light;
    text-align: justify;

    p{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .ingrijirea-options {
        margin-top: 30px;
        p {
            margin-bottom: 7px;
        }
        p:hover {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="ingrijirea">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ingrijirea-main">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="ingrijirea-title">
                    <p class="ingrijirea-title-top">Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p class="ingrijirea-title-bottom">Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ingrijirea-text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                    <div class="ingrijirea-options">
                        <p class="ingrijirea-option">Lorem ipsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that with this code not only this section, but the whole page is transforming to `font-weight:light` and I have no idea why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the declaration should change

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: light;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Italic.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: the problem persists, it even got more unclear. All the elements where I've added `font-weight:lighter` are now bold..